# Finding out the shared hosting providers located in a particular data center

Tags: web-hosting

I know the physical location of data-centers that I want my website hosted in. One of these is located on **350 E Cermack in Chicago, IL**. My problem is that I am looking for all the providers of low-cost shared hosting in this data center. Do you have a list? And if you do have such a list can you please tell me how you came up with it?

I know many discount hosting providers are physically located in the Arizona-Utah areas. But I am located near Chicago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real way to do this besides asking the data center operators. But you seem to be going about things the wrong way. Most people look for good shared hosting providers and then pick one that has data centers in their desired region. Data centers are pretty much commodity services. It's the managed hosting services built on top of them that differentiate different web hosts. So it makes no sense to pick a data center out and then try to find which hosts use it.

Even if you're doing this because you're targeting users who live in a very small area, there's no guarantee that the closest data center will provide the best performance. Internet traffic takes the most direct route based on [network topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_topology), which isn't always the most direct or shortest route geographically. Peering arrangements, routing policies, physical infrastructure, traffic patterns, etc. all affect the network topology. So it doesn't really make sense to choose hosts based on street address.

You'd be much better off googling for shared hosting providers in Chicago and then testing the performance of sites hosted by each web host.

Comment: This would be better if there wasn't so much spam in the search results. Everybody wants to be first place, even if their service is poor!

Comment: @unixman83: Yea, unfortunately search engines have limited info to work with, and with all the blackhat/greyhat SEO, search ranking has more to do with keyword stuffing, spamming, etc. than service quality. But what you can do is get a short list this way and then narrow it down by finding reputable reviews on webmaster forums. Another approach is to examine the SLA. This doesn't guarantee that you'll get good performance, but it _does_ guarantee that you'll be compensated if the SLA isn't met. Usually hosting with good SLAs are pretty good, if perhaps more expensive.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with @Lèsemajesté but to answer your exact question, the [data centre's website is here](http://steadfast.net/corporate/chicago.datacenter.php), and their phone number is at the bottom of the page (312.602.2689).

If you really want to just call them and ask!

But @Lèsemajesté is completely correct in his answer to your question, you may also have a think about implementing a Free CDN as this would solve or mitigate the problem without it mattering where your actual server is located.